# How to change the address of processing a form in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have Yii2 and a simple form. (It's view):

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
 <?= $form->field($form_model, 'name') ?>
 <?= $form->field($form_model, 'email') ?>
 <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

But the form will send the request to the same address, which is itself: /myform

```
<form id="w0" action="/myform" method="post">
```

How I can change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting param `action` in `ActiveForm` configuration:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'here_array_or_string']) ?>
```

More in [Yii2 Active Form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$action-detail)

Answer (score 2):

Add it in the widget configuration like:

```
ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['controller/action']])
```